# Ignition Effect Priority in Old Yu-Gi-Oh!

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I am trying to remember the details of the old mechanic in Yu-Gi-Oh! which was referred to borderline-erroneously as priority, but was actually an ability to use ignition effects in response to Summons.  According to my recollection:

1. Only the turn player could use it
2. It could only be used if the monster Summoned was the turn player's
3. It could only be used during Main Phase 1 or Main Phase 2, the game phases when ignition effect can normally be used
4. It could be used to activate the ignition effect of one monster anywhere in the turn player's possession (hand, field, Graveyard, etc.)
5. It could be used in response to any type of Summon (Normal, Flip, or Special)
6. It could only be used if the Summon was the last event to occur, in exactly the same sense as "When...you can" trigger effects.

Are there any mistakes so far?  Also, to further expand on the meaning of #2:

7. Could the turn player activate an ignition effect in response to Special Summoning Lava Golem to the non-turn player's field?
8. Could the turn player activate an ignition effect in response to the non-turn player resolving Ojama Trio as Chain link 1 during the Main Phase (Ojama Trio uses a "you Special Summon to your opponent's field" wording)?
9. Could the turn player activate an ignition effect in response to the non-turn player resolving Inferno Reckless Summon as Chain link 1 during the Main Phase (Inferno Reckless Summon uses a "your opponent Special Summons to their own field" wording)?
10. If Remove Brainwashing was active, could the turn player activate an ignition effect in response to their Summoning a monster to their own field that was owned by the non-turn player (after control of the Summoned monster immediately shifted to the non-turn player)?
11. If Remove Brainwashing was active, could the turn player activate an ignition effect in response to the non-turn player Summoning a monster to the non-turn player's field that was owned by the turn player (after control of the Summoned monster immediately shifted to the turn player)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Correct.
2. Going further, only the monster that was summoned would be allowed to activate its ignition effect (which answers 7 and 8).
3. Also correct due to ignition effects being treated as having spell speed 1.
4. Incorrect, only the summoned monster would be allowed to activate its ignition effect with ignition effect priority.
5. Correct.
6. Correct, however I also believe that it cannot be a summon during the resolution of a chain (by card effect such as polymerization), for a special summon it would have to be by summoning condition.
7. Answered in 2.
8. Answered in 2.
9. No, answered in 6.
10. No, answered in 2 as the summoned monster would be in the opponents control.
11. No, as you cannot summon monsters via summoning condition on your opponents turn.